# How to re-run a failed test only once using xunit.retry?

Tags: .net, selenium, xunit, specflow

I am using Xunit.retry to re-run my failed test cases but the issue that I am facing is this that a test runs twice when it is failed and thus my script execution time has increased exponentially. I want my tests to re-run only once on the event of failure. When I use retry(1) then the test doesn't re-run.

[image: Snapshot of my scenario]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation here](https://github.com/giggio/xunit-retry), `@retry` is the default and it is retrying three times, so try to use `@retry(1)` or `@retry(2)`

Comment: @retry(1) is not re-running the test once it is failed.